# ncurses error on windows 8.1 when compiling

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am just completely lost while trying to compile a simple ncurces demo program in c. It looks like some kind of linker error and it happens no matter what flags I pass to gcc on Windows / Cygwin

```
> /cygdrive/c/Users/me/Documents/demo.c:4:30: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
                              ^
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `initscr'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `initscr'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `noecho'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x1a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `noecho'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `curs_set'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x24): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `curs_set'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `endwin'
/tmp/cc6mTQ2P.o:demo.c:(.text+0x33): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `endwin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

enter code here
```

Comment: How do you compile/link your program?

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] **including the makefile or compilation command** to build it.

Answer (score 0):

in order to resolve this error try using the -lncurses flag added to your gcc compiler arguments.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.